# Короткие теги PHP <? ?> в Blade

Tags: laravel, php7, blade

Есть уже готовый проект на Laravel 5.5 который нужно поддерживать. При установке на локальный сервер выпадают ошибки на представлениях 
Undefined variable: cat_products (View:/resources/views/types/category/index.blade.php)

Проблема в том, что в начале почти каждой вьюшки есть код PHP, который прописан в коротких тегах , где объявляются эти переменные. Соответственно Blade их не видит.

Помогает, если заменить их на @php @endphp. Но вьюшек почти сотня. Плюс сайт уже работает как-то с ними на рабочем сервере.

Comment: А в чем вопрос?

Comment: @Budimir Как может работать код PHP в тегах <? ?> в Blade? На локальной машине у меня выдает ошибки, а на сервере работает. Чтобы заработало на локалке, заменил эти теги на `@php` `@endphp` Есть ли какие-то настройки для чтения тегов?

Answer (score 0):

Измените у себя в настройках PHP ( файл `php.ini` )
значение

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

на

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

НО. Такое обьявление переменных в blade шаблонах - признак не очень хорошего стиля кода. Советую изучить документацию, и переделать сайт согласно HMVC паттерну.